# Integrating Youtube in Android

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am trying to integrate youtube into my Android app. I have the following code to queue the video

```
 fun setUpYoutubePlayer()
{
    val youtubeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.songYoutubeFragment)
            as YouTubePlayerFragment

    youtubeFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_key),
            object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, b: Boolean) {
                    // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.song_youtube_id)))

                }

                override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider,
                                                     youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            })

}
```

Now sometimes I won't have the video id. But I will always have the name of the song and the album name. How can I queue the video with the name and the album name of the song.

Comment: I donot know which youtube client you are using, but if you are using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi I could help

Comment: Yes its YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi. @AshishKumar

Comment: See this, https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858..They have made a class utility functions, which would let you get the id's of songs for your search query, using which you could proceed

Comment: I tried to open that link. It says page not Found. Can you please check if the link is correct

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-youtube-client-on-android--cms-22858

Comment: You can try this link https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/android-youtube-player-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we will teach you how to play a YouTube video in an Android App. So here YouTube will be embedded in Android App itself. This we will do through the Youtube Player API developed by Google. You can read more about it here. A major application of android youtube player is that now you can directly upload video to YouTube and stream it in your App. You can see a demo of this youtube android player API example below:

https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/android-youtube-player-api/